# How to predict product sales?

Tags: time-series, prediction

I have a set of data that represents the number of products sold per day during three months and I need to predict the sales for the next two weeks. How could I do this? This is a sample of the data I have. I tried to do this with Box-Jenkins, but it didn`t work.

```
7 6 5 7 9 10 9 7 4 5 4 6 7 10 7 5 6 3 6 8 7 5 4 2 3 5 6 7 9 12 13 10 ...
```

Comment: You have only 32 data points. How is that 3 months worth of data? If you have missing values, then you will need to use the time stamps as well. If you are showing a subset for some sort of test/train split or cross validation, you need be careful as those not as straightforward with time series as they are with other ML and stats problems.

Answer (score 1):

You submitted 32 values . Is that all you have for 3 months of data ? With 32 values this is what I obtained via Box-Jenkins . Here is the actual/fit/forecast using monte carlo re-sampling of model errors without future pulses [image] with this equation [image] .

Now enabling the possibility of future anomalies/pulses we get [image]

Perhaps your software or you didn't identify a model that included possible anomalies ( period 14 & 18 ) ... always a distinct possibility.

I used AUTOBOX which automatically identified this model. The acf/pacf of the original series is fairly clear as to a possible model .[image] . The two "spikes" in the partial along with the "decay" in the acf suggest an ar(2) model . The initial model that was identified is here [image] suggesting 2 possible anomalies ( period 14 and 18 ). When two indicator (pulse) series were added this was the final model [image].

The 14 forecasts are presented graphically here [image] and tabularly here [image] . Note that two sets of forecasts are presented. The first 3 columns represent a monte carlo simulation (re-sampling the model residuals allowing for future anomalies) and the standard +- symmetrical limits assuming normality of the model residuals and no future pulses.

Here is the histogram of the model residuals ...   [image] visually suggesting significant deviation from normality.

I am quite shocked that a trivial example like this caused eviews to fail.

Comment: Ia a subset, but I tried to do this with Eviews.What did you use or how did you obtain those results?

Comment: Also, I would need the values that are predicted, not only the graphic.